# Define hues by column values in seaborn barplot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I would like the colour of the columns to be determined by their value on the x-axis, e.g.  bars with identical values on the x-axis should have identical colours assigned to them.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B','C','D','E','F'],data={'col1':np.array([2.3423,4.435,9.234,9.234,2.456,6.435])})
ax = sns.barplot(x='col1', y=df.index.values, data=df,palette='magma')
```

This is what it looks like at the moment with default settings. I presume there is a simple elegant way of doing this, but interested in any solution.

[image]

Comment: Did you try specifying the hue? Aka adding `hue='col1'` as an argument to `sns.barplot`.

Comment: that doesnt fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a solution:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
  data={'col1':np.array([2.3423,4.435,9.234,9.234,2.456,6.435])})
ax = sns.barplot(x='col1', y=df.index.values, data=df,
  palette=mpl.cm.magma(df['col1']*.1))
```

Note: `mpl.cm.magma` is a [`Colormap`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap) instance and is used to convert data values (floats) from the interval [0, 1] to colors that the `Colormap` represents.  If you want "auto scaling" of your data values, you could use `palette=mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='magma').to_rgba(df['col1'])` instead in the `sns.barplot()` call.

Here the output:[image: barplot]

Comment: You should use a matplotlib normalize object to avoid hand-specifying the scalar factor here.

Comment: @mwaskom, the `ScalarMappable` option I suggested in my note uses a `Normalize` object automatically, see [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable).  The colors looked prettier in the hand-specified version, though.  :)

Comment: Oops totally missed the paragraph after the code, sorry!

Comment: PS: a `Normalize`-based version would be: `palette=mpl.cm.magma(mpl.colors.Normalize()(df['col1']))`.  Had left this out of the answer since two options seemed enough.